# Miktex can't be reached

Tags: miktex, installing, miktex-update

Yesterday I ran the Miktex update on both admin and non-admin (on Windows 10), but now when I run a latex file, it asks to run the package manager, and cannot find any packages.

So I tried updating Miktex and get the error "Sorry but something went wrong, couldn't connect to server".

So I tried re-installing Miktex but the download fails "This site can’t be reached, mirror.aarnet.edu.au took too long to respond." This also happens on my android. But http://www.websitenotworking.com/miktex.org says Miktex is working! I tried disabling my firewall and ad-blocker temporarily but this made no difference. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe change repository?

Comment: I changed to some German repository, that managed to at least install one package...,  are there any particularly reliable repositories?

Comment: Personally, I use `distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr` which is a French university (in Paris). But `ftp.dante.de` is quite fast too.

Comment: I have the same error. "Bad request" "code="7", url="https://api2.miktex.org/hello" while checking for updates. Maybe somthings wrong with the server.

Comment: After changing the repository, I could then download miktex from miktex.org (weird), and reinstall from scratch. It now works fine.

Comment: i am getting the same window that server cant be reached

Comment: are you able to change repository?